# Rarely occurring ConcurrentModificationException in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Sometimes i'm experiencing the following exception while starting of webserver itself. Could not figure out the reason why its happening, is it something to do with Spring or wildfly server?, What could be the reason causing this exception ?

```
12:34:15,711 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] 
(MSC service thread 1-4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization
completed in 32747 ms
12:34:15,714 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]  
(MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:195)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you share you context.Xml?

Comment: There are more than 20 modules (java & webapp) 20*4 context.xml and context java config available as an EAR deployment. If you could tell me which portion of the config you may required to help me out like any one module's spring mvc config ? we are using locatorFactorySelector, parentContextKey to load some of the beans globally as well.

Comment: OK, so hence it happen while it loads the context it seems 2 of your springBeans uses the same list.

Comment: Can you be more specific on this ? you mean my application code is generating this ?

Comment: Yes, seems like it your code

Comment: Were not facing since spring 4.2.2 upgrade, hope spring 4.2.2 fixed the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could be hitting [Spring Framework bug SPR-13123](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13123) ConcurrentModificationException in DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType()

Comment: Exactly, me too experiencing in wildfly server thats too very rarely and can't reproduce.